# Sending Empty GET Requests to PHP, but handle the request?

Tags: php, nginx

**EDIT** I updated my configuration like below:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/tag/([^/]*)$ /tag/?tag=$1 break;
}
```

This worked.

---

How would I have a file structure like this:

```
/
 /tags
  index.php
```

Look like this in the URL:
https://example.com/tags/animals

("animals" being the tag, but the page gets animals in a $_GET or some method alike)

I can't have a seperate page for each tag since tags are dynamically made, I figured there would be something to do with rewrite rules. I use nginx as my server, so how would I do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute GET request like bellow.

`http://myproject/tags/tag1,tag2,tag3`

Bellow for URL rewrite.

`location /tags { 
rewrite ^/tags/([^/]*)$ /tags/?tags=$1 break; }`

Comment: I am using Nginx not Apache. Also the url has to be like this: https://example.com/tags/animals (animals is the tag)

Comment: I get a 403 forbidden error when using this. Any ideas?

Comment: You sorta got it right, I updated my answer with what worked.